# Counting total IDs in a table for changing dates using Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

So let's say I have some data as follows. It is a table where the distinct identifier for each row is the `ID` + the `MONTH_END`.

**TABLE1**

```
ID  MONTH_END        data
001 2022-03-31      grape
001 2022-04-30     orange
001 2022-05-31  pineapple
002 2021-01-31      berry
002 2021-02-28     banana
003 2019-02-28     orange   
003 2021-12-31      grape     
003 2022-01-31     banana      
003 2019-02-28     orange
```

My goal here is I want to make a new variable called `frequency` where I take a new table and determine **how many distinct times the `ID` appears before and during the `MONTH_END` in table1.**

**TABLE2**

```
ID   freq_date  freq_val
001 2022-03-31         4
002 2022-02-20       242
003 2021-12-31       122
004 2020-07-02       342
001 2021-08-23        44
001 2021-01-13      7347
003 2021-01-21       212
```

Additionally, I would like the sum of the `freq_vals` in the same fashion called `freq_val2`.

Final expected output:

```
ID  MONTH_END        data  frequency freq_val2
001 2022-03-31      grape          3      7395  
001 2022-04-30     orange          3      7395
001 2022-05-31  pineapple          3      7395
002 2021-01-31      berry          0         0
002 2021-02-28     banana          1       242
003 2019-02-28     orange          0         0
003 2021-12-31      grape          1       122
003 2022-01-31     banana          2       334
003 2019-02-28     orange          2       334
```

Comment: I wrote a query that I believe is accurate in the answer below, but some of the test data above appears incorrect.  For instance, in Table_1 the row 003 2019-02-28     orange appears twice (rows 6 and 9).  In Table_2 the row 002 2022-02-20       242 exceeds the largest month_end value in Table_1 for ID 002, therefore would not appear in the results.  Please correct if I misunderstand your data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic is correct in the query, but I'm unable to obtain the same results as shown above - please read my comment regarding some questions about your test data (duplicate rows, and values that exceed the logic threshold described).

```
-- 
-- Create tables and populate with test data 
--
create
or replace table table_1 (id varchar, month_end date, data varchar);

insert into
    table_1
values
    ('001','2022-03-31'::date,'grape'), 
    ('001','2022-04-30'::date,'orange'), 
    ('001','2022-05-31'::date,'pineapple'), 
    ('002','2021-01-31'::date,'berry'), 
    ('002','2021-02-28'::date,'banana'), 
    ('003','2019-02-28'::date,'orange'), 
    ('003','2021-12-31'::date,'grape'), 
    ('003','2022-01-31'::date,'banana'), 
    ('003','2019-02-28'::date,'orange'); 
    
create
    or replace table table_2 (id varchar, freq_date date, freq_val integer);
insert into
    table_2
values
    ('001','2022-03-31'::date, 4),
    ('002','2022-02-20'::date, 242),
    ('003','2021-12-31'::date, 122),
    ('004','2020-07-02'::date, 342),
    ('001','2021-08-23'::date, 44),
    ('001','2021-01-13'::date, 7347),
    ('003','2021-01-21'::date, 212);

--
-- Results query
--
select
    t1.id,
    t1.month_end,
    t1.data,
    count(t2.id) as frequency,
    sum(nvl(t2.freq_val, 0)) as freq_val2
from
    table_1 t1
    left join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    and t2.freq_date <= t1.month_end
group by
    1,
    2,
    3
order by
    1,
    2;
```

Results:

```
ID  MONTH_END   DATA        FREQUENCY   FREQ_VAL2
001 2022-03-31  grape       3           7395
001 2022-04-30  orange      3           7395
001 2022-05-31  pineapple   3           7395
002 2021-01-31  berry       0           0
002 2021-02-28  banana      0           0
003 2019-02-28  orange      0           0
003 2021-12-31  grape       2           334
003 2022-01-31  banana      2           334
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE AS (
 select '001' ID,  '2022-03-31'::DATE MONTH_END,      'grape' DATA UNION ALL
 select '001' ID,  '2022-04-30'::DATE MONTH_END,     'orange' DATA UNION ALL
 select '001' ID,  '2022-05-31'::DATE MONTH_END,  'pineapple' DATA UNION ALL
 select '002' ID,  '2021-01-31'::DATE MONTH_END,      'berry' DATA UNION ALL
 select '002' ID,  '2021-02-28'::DATE MONTH_END,     'banana' DATA UNION ALL
 select '003' ID,  '2019-02-28'::DATE MONTH_END,     'orange' DATA UNION ALL   
 select '003' ID,  '2021-12-31'::DATE MONTH_END,      'grape' DATA UNION ALL     
 select '003' ID,  '2022-01-31'::DATE MONTH_END,     'banana' DATA UNION ALL      
 select '003' ID,  '2019-02-28'::DATE MONTH_END,     'orange' DATA )

 SELECT ID, MONTH_END, COUNT(1) FREQ, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) 
 FROM CTE 
 GROUP BY
      ID, MONTH_END;
```

[image]